# Inserting many records to database using Laravel's Chunk method becomes slower over time

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, chunking

So basically I am trying to import data into around 15 different tables into my database from another. I am chunking the data from the source database, and within that function callback I am inserting it into my database using raw SQL. Code example:

```
foreach($tables as $table) {    
     DB::connection('source_db')->table($table)->select($fields)->orderBy('id'))->chunk(2500, function($records) use($table) {
          $this->runInsertQuery($records, $table);
     });
}
```

There are around 2 million records total, it seems that it starts out very fast but gets slower and slower as it moves from table to table, taking hours to complete. I was under the impression based on Laravel's documentation that chunking would make inserts run much faster, but it seems to be having the opposite effect. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use tool designed to do this its called `mysqldump`.

Comment: 'chunking would make inserts run much faster' faster than not chunking, not just "faster and faster as time goes on".

Comment: But my question is what is causing it to move slower and slower as time goes on, and what can I do to prevent that?

Comment: Have you monitored your applications memory usage? I could imagine that over time, the script is using almost all available memory which requires the garbage collector to do its job properly. With smaller scripts you often don't even see the garbage collector working because the script ends before you run out of memory. So maybe try with more memory and monitor your memory. You could also try if adding `gc_collect_cycles()` (forces garbage collection) at the end or after each chunk changes something.

Comment: [There is also a good article about gc and how to solve possible issues with it.](https://tideways.com/profiler/blog/how-to-optimize-the-php-garbage-collector-usage-to-improve-memory-and-performance) By the way, I had similar issues with the laravel/scout package when importing a large amount of rows, also quite likely because of the chunk method. So I might be able to investigate on this myself as well.

Comment: You should isolate the performance slowdown. Is it part of the reading and chunking? Or is it part of the insertion process? You could try replacing `$this->runInsertQuery($records, $table)` with a function that does nothing, and see if you still get the slowdown. If you do, try making your chunks bigger. The cause of that possible slowdown? The reading of the chunk takes an amount of time proportional to how many chunks have already been read.  `... LIMIT 2500 OFFSET 25000000` might be quite slow.

Comment: @O.Jones you're right, the reading of the chunks is taking increasingly longer for each chunk, that seems to be the source of the slowdown. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Can you show the definition of the table you're reading? (`SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename`) ?  Please [edit] your question.